# Why God can't exec command starting with `RAILS_ENV`

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, god

I am deploying a project to a environment where multiple application is deployed. So I uses rvm to separated the running environment of each Rails application.

In my application, I use gem `god` to manage my delayed_job processes, in my god file I had:

```
God.watch do |w| 
  ...
  w.start = "RAILS_ENV=#{RAILS_ENV} /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm in #{RAILS_ROOT} do #{RAILS_ROOT}/script/delayed_job -n 1 start"
  ...
end
```

but for this, God reports:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327-falcon@global/gems/god-0.13.2/lib/god/process.rb:324:in `exec': No such file or directory - RAILS_ENV=staging /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm in /home/deployer/deploy/myproject/current do /home/deployer/deploy/myproject/current/script/delayed_job stop (Errno::ENOENT)
```

And if I change it to:

```
w.start = "export RAILS_ENV=#{RAILS_ENV} /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm in #{RAILS_ROOT} do #{RAILS_ROOT}/script/delayed_job -n 1 start"
```

it works. I would like to know if added `export` is the correct way to do it in a multiple application environment, since on that server, there a other applications runs under `RAILS_ENV=production`, will them be affected?

**UPDATE**

I just found that I was wrong, with adding `export` to the beginning, `God` still throws me the same error, how could I achieve this?

Thanks & Best Regards.

Comment: Can God make a rock so heavy he can't lift it? Hah! Where's your omnipotence now, my pretty? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I learnt that I have to do it like this:

`w.start = "/usr/bin/env RAILS_ENV=#{RAILS_ENV} /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm in #{RAILS_ROOT} do #{RAILS_ROOT}/script/delayed_job -n 1 start"`

Then it's ok.